# How to segment femur from x-ray in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My goal is to segment the bone from an x-ray image, more specifically the femur bone.

### Input image 1:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

### Input image 2:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

### Input image 3:

[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

So far I applied K-means segmentation (with 5 clusters). However, I don't know how to go from here, or it is the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

### UPDATE:

I implemented template matching as suggested in the comments, which allows cropping to the zone of interest ( the ball joint).
Which got me this:

[image]

I have then applied the following:

1. Applied CLAHE to enhance borders

```py
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(4,4))
img_clahe = clahe.apply(image_slice)

plt.imshow(img_clahe, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
```

[image]

2. Applied Median Blur to smooth image:

```py
blur= cv2.medianBlur(img_clahe, 9)
plt.imshow(blur, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
```

[image]

3. Applied Adaptive Tresholding:

```py
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
th3 = cv2.morphologyEx(th3, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
th3 = cv2.medianBlur(th3, 9)

plt.imshow(th3, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
```

[image]

Although I feel like I'm closer, it's still not exactly what I want. Any suggestion?
I want to get this contour:

[image]

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty solution you might want to try before you go the neural nets way. That would require quite a bit of data for training. In these images take the most prominent feature of the femur bone, say the ball joint, and do a template matching using it on scaled down versions of images. You can do that on a segmented image or on the original image. Get the contour that has the template matched part within it should roughly be your femur bone. Assuming your segmentation is about right you have the femur bone else do whatever post processing that is required.

Comment: Will template matching work for multiple images?

Comment: Well, the assumption is that the femur bone ball joint will characteristically have that shape irrespective of the angle it is taken, and that feature is not present in the other part of the xray. You might have to visually check that and keep a lower threshold to pass similar looking ball joints. As I said, it's something worth trying out before moving to a much more involving neural nets solution, which, undoubtedly, would require quite a bit of data itself.

Comment: @KnightForked I've updated my question with your sugestions. Take a look :)

Comment: You are pretty close to your solution. Why not try a few morphological operations (morphological open or even erase in this case) in your final image to open up the separate bone parts and then do a findContours. Any contour that encompasses center then is your femur bone with a decently high probability. In the end you might have to fine tune all the parameters to generalize this approach.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @KnightForked haven't worked on this (other priority tasks), but no. I still have no solution

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my last but one comment (dated May 22nd) on this thread? See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want reasonable results you will have to use a deep neural network (semantic segmentation task). But you will need classified data for it (images with segmentation masks).

Comment: First I want to see how far I can go without ML/Deep Learning. To then compare the results with a Deep Learning approach

Comment: Do you have more images for reference? it's hard to infer such things from one image.. however, if you want to do it in a semi-supervised manner, you can use the watershed algorithm, or other segmentation algorithms (like graph cut)

Comment: Yes, I do. I Will update the question with 2 more images.