# contour detection for hip prosthesis

Tags: image-processing, opencv, medical, python

I'm new to image processing and try to use python and open cv to find contour of hip prothesis from x-ray images. I tried to use many ways and applied many tutorials on contour detection such as binary threshold, histogram equalization, un-sharp masking. Also, I tried to use filters such as DoF but the result is very noisy.

The best result I had achieved via applying the following:

```
img = cv2.imread(image_Path) 
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(grey_img ,60,200)
contours, hi = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

**Input example #1**

[image: input1 example]

**Input example #2**

[image: inpu2 example]

**Input example #3**

[image: input3 example]

**Result**

[image: result]

---

I tried to apply histogram equalization before canny method but the result was worse.

could you please help me on the best way to detect the full prosthesis and how to remove the other detected contours.
Also how to deal with images with different contrast because not all x-rays with clear prothesis.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: From the image, looks like the prothesis is having a constant pixel value, unlike real bones. If this is always true for all your images, then your approach should be find a large monotone area with the target pixel value. You may have a hard-coded target pixel value, or get that value by analyzing the histogram or other properties, then by thresholding or some image segmentation algorithm, you should be able to extract out the prothesis. Please give it a try and post your intermediate results, so people can help you more.

Comment: Please post the original image(s) for others to try a solution. See if this could be of any help https://stackoverflow.com/q/67624759/10333818

Comment: It might be useful to invert the input images to get  closer to what the sensor is reading. At least for me that's easier to reason about. (The metal prostheses absorb xrays, so that's low signal area, flesh and air don't so the black is high signal area) | Example image #1 looks quite nice. | Example image #2 has a big underexposed piece on the top-right corner... maybe a lead shield there. Also the label. You may have to exclude those areas before looking for the target. | Example image #3 seems underexposed, maybe some normalization would help. ...(cont)

Comment: And then there is that thick line cutting across the prosthesis...some metal rod perhaps? What is the expected result in this case? Just the V shaped part of the prosthesis? or both of those high absorption objects?